# Standardizing color for multiple pie plots

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am using this as an example to deal with a different problem. The dataset I am actually using has about a hundred values that would be included in the labels variables. I am trying to standardize the colors used in the pie plot so that in both plots 'Jerry' will have the same color segment in both plots for example.

What is the best and most efficient way to do this? You can see from this output that the colors of each segment of the pie are different.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels1 = ['John', 'Jerry', 'Sharon']
labels2 = ['Jerry', 'Sharon', 'Shaun']
y1 = [12, 8, 5]
y2 = [10, 5, 10]

# create a figure that contains all the plots that I want 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 20))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.95,
                    wspace=0.1, hspace=0.2)
# assigning each subplot to a variable to make it easier to plot 

ax1 = axs[0,0]
ax2 = axs[0,1]


ax1.pie(y1,labels = labels1)
ax2.pie(y2, labels= labels2)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_colors = {'John': 'blue',
             'Jerry': 'green',
             'Sharon': (0.75, 0.15, 0.55), #RGB way
             'Shaun': 'red'
             }

colors1 = [my_colors[name] for name in labels1]
colors2 = [my_colors[name] for name in labels2]

ax1.pie(y1, labels=labels1, colors=colors1)
ax2.pie(y2, labels=labels2, colors=colors2)
```